# c# different versions in same assembly

Tags: c#

when i decompilation assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core in my project 
I got stuck seeing string

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
d:\Projects\tb\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll
#endregion
```

In first sting specified version 2.0.0.0
 In second string  specified  version 2.2.1
Which version I use? how could this happen?

Answer (score 2):

- 2.2.1 is a version of **NuGet** package **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core** that contains Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll.
- 2.0.0 is a version of **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll**.